# Conectar Java a MySQl

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

> Quiero hacer una conexion a base de datos donde pueda agregar datos por medio de teclado a una tabla ya creada pero me meustra error y no se como hacerle, la verdad estoy aprendiendo y ocupa ayuda pd. si me pueden pasar los cambios y las bajas de estos datos se los agredeceria mucho xd

```js
package hi;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Hi {

    import java.sql.*;
    import java.io.*;
    public class Mostrar {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, IOException{
  BufferedReader key= new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
         String user, password;
  System.out.println("Usuario");
  user=key.readLine();
  System.out.println("contraseña");
  password=key.readLine();
   
  try {
        Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/agenda", user, password);
        Statement st = conexion.createStatement();
        st.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS personal;");
        st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE personal (`Identificador` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `Nombre` varchar(50) NOT NULL, `Apellidos` varchar(50) NOT NULL, `Telefono` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL, `Email` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`Identificador`));");
        st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO personal (`Identificador`, `Nombre`, `Apellidos`, `Telefono`, `Email`) VALUES (1, 'José', 'Martínez López', '968112233', 'jose@martinezlopez.com'), (2, 'María', 'Gómez Muñoz', '911876876', 'maria@gomezoliver.com'), (3, 'Juan', 'Sánchez Fernández', '922111333', 'juan@sanchezfernandez.com'), (4, 'Ana', 'Murcia Rodríguez', '950999888', 'ana@murciarodriguez.com');");
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM personal;");
  
        if (rs != null) {
            System.out.println("El listado de persona es el siguiente:");
  
            while (rs.next()) {
                   System.out.println("  ID: " + rs.getObject("Identificador"));
                   System.out.println("  Nombre completo: " + rs.getObject("Nombre") + " " + rs.getObject("Apellidos"));
                   System.out.println("  Contacto: " + rs.getObject("Telefono") + " " + rs.getObject("Email"));
                   System.out.println("- ");
             }
             rs.close();
         }
         st.close();
  
     }
     catch(SQLException s)
     {
         System.out.println("Error: SQL.");
         System.out.println("SQLException: " + s.getMessage());
     }
     catch(Exception s)
     {
         System.out.println("Error: Varios.");
         System.out.println("SQLException: " + s.getMessage());
     }
         System.out.println("FIN DE EJECUCIÓN.");
     }

   }
```

Comment: añade el error que te muestra

Comment: Simplemente no me deja ni ingresar a mi base de datos cuando antes si lo hacia y lo unico que hice fue apagr la pc y prenderla de nuevo

Comment: ya te aseguraste que tu servidor de mysql este encendido? si usas xampp por ejemplo debes abrir el panel y ver que mysql aparezca en verdad corriendoo desde la consola revisa si haciendo `mysql -u root -p` y metiendo la contraseña te deja ingresar

Comment: Ya y me muestra ahora este error SQLException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: Si ya pero ahora me muestra este error SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/agenda

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que tienes añadido el driver de jdbc a la librería, te faltaría añadir la importación de esta.

Para ello necesitas crear una variable del driver como esta:

```
String driverJDBC= "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
```

Y después inportar el driver antes de intentar conectar, tal que así:

```
Class.forName(driverJDBC);
```

Si metemos estos dos pasos a tu código quedaria algo así:

```
package hi;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Hi {

    import java.sql.*;
    import java.io.*;
    public class Mostrar {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, IOException{
            BufferedReader key= new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String user, password;
            String driverJDBC= "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            System.out.println("Usuario");
            user=key.readLine();
            System.out.println("contraseña");
            password=key.readLine();

            try {
                Class.forName(driverJDBC);
                Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/agenda", user, password);
                Statement st = conexion.createStatement();
                st.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS personal;");
                st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE personal (`Identificador` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `Nombre` varchar(50) NOT NULL, `Apellidos` varchar(50) NOT NULL, `Telefono` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL, `Email` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`Identificador`));");
                st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO personal (`Identificador`, `Nombre`, `Apellidos`, `Telefono`, `Email`) VALUES (1, 'José', 'Martínez López', '968112233', 'jose@martinezlopez.com'), (2, 'María', 'Gómez Muñoz', '911876876', 'maria@gomezoliver.com'), (3, 'Juan', 'Sánchez Fernández', '922111333', 'juan@sanchezfernandez.com'), (4, 'Ana', 'Murcia Rodríguez', '950999888', 'ana@murciarodriguez.com');");
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM personal;");

                if (rs != null) {
                    System.out.println("El listado de persona es el siguiente:");

                    while (rs.next()) {
                        System.out.println("  ID: " + rs.getObject("Identificador"));
                        System.out.println("  Nombre completo: " + rs.getObject("Nombre") + " " + rs.getObject("Apellidos"));
                        System.out.println("  Contacto: " + rs.getObject("Telefono") + " " + rs.getObject("Email"));
                        System.out.println("- ");
                    }
                    rs.close();
                }
                st.close();

            }
            catch(SQLException s)
            {
                System.out.println("Error: SQL.");
                System.out.println("SQLException: " + s.getMessage());
            }
            catch(Exception s)
            {
                System.out.println("Error: Varios.");
                System.out.println("SQLException: " + s.getMessage());
            }
            System.out.println("FIN DE EJECUCIÓN.");
        }

        }
```

Espero que esto te sirva.